# Getting the 'content' from a Rich Text Content Control

Tags: vba, ms-word, richtext

I need to get the 'contents' of a Rich Text Content Control in Word, and paste that content into another Rich Text Content Control (formatted).

Here's the code I have:

```
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("original").Item(1).Range.FormattedText.Copy
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("duplicate").Item(1).Range.Paste
```

Which **seems** to work, but it's copying the entire original ContentControl into (nested) the duplicate ContentControl... and I just want the formatted text alone.

original and duplicate content which is nested

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
With ActiveDocument
  .SelectContentControlsByTitle("duplicate")(1).Range.FormattedText = _
  .SelectContentControlsByTitle("original")(1).Range.FormattedText
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

### Rather than use vba for this, Map the Content Controls.

For Rich Text controls, you will need to map the XML parts.

> ***Data Mapping***
>
> The real power of content controls lies in their ability to be mapped
> (or bound) to a custom XML data store embedded in the Word 2007/2010
> OfficeOpenXML format document file. Through this binding:
>
> - Any changes in the data store data is automatically repeated in all content controls mapped to that data.
> - Any changes to a mapped content control automatically updates the data store and all other content controls mapped to that data store
>   data.

[Word Content Controls](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html) by Greg Maxey

While you can do this yourself, why? There are a number of free tools that will do it for you.

- [Mayor & Maxey CC/V/B & DV Tools Add-In](https://Mayor%20&%20Maxey%20CC/V/B%20and%20DP%20Tools%20Add-In)
- [Content Control Tools](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_tools.html) by Greg Maxey
- [Insert Content Controls Add-In](https://www.gmayor.com/insert_content_control_addin.htm) by Graham Mayor
- [Custom Content Control Dialog Add-In](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/Content_Control_Custom_Insert_Dialog.html) by Greg Maxey

I am sure there are more out there but I have used the above tools. They have different interfaces and powers but all of them give you the ability to add a Mapped Content Control to a document, including a Rich Text one.